# Have a draggable item in jsPlumb which is made of multiple items

Tags: jsplumb

I'd like to create a single draggable item in jsPlumb which is actually composed of multiple items: a "main item" which has an anchor which is a connection target (`isTarget: true`), and multiple "sub items" which display stacked up, each of which has an anchor which is a connection source. Something like this:

[image]

Subthings should always be presented in the way above; they aren't draggable around inside the item, nor are they draggable to other items. Dragging anywhere on the main item or any subitem drags the whole group around from place to place.

Am I best to model this as separate things in a `jsPlumb.Group`, or is this really all just one "wrapper" div with many divs inside it? If it's the latter, how do I add anchors to the main and subitems *within* the wrapper, if it's the wrapper that I tell jsPlumb about?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this Just Works.

```
const a = document.createElement("article");
const d = document.createElement("div");
const p = document.createElement("p");
a.appendChild(d);
a.appendChild(p);
pane.appendChild(a);
jsPlumb.draggable(a);
var endpoint1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint(d, { isTarget:true, anchors: ["Top"] });
var endpoint2 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint(p, { isSource:true, anchors: ["Right"] });
```

Create a "wrapper" (here `a`, an `article`), and mark it draggable; append subitems to it, and add Endpoints to them; everything works. Done.